# Pin image depending on the settings in the plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, image, plist

I have a plist with many points with this construction:

```
Category1
-item0
 -name
 -coordinates
-item1
 -name
 -coordinates
-item2
 -name
 -coordinates

Category2
-item0
 -name
 -coordinates
-item1
 -name
 -coordinates
-item2
 -name
 -coordinates
```

now I show pin image with this:

```
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin1.png"];
```

**how can I show different pin images for different categories "Category1, Category2"? Many thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the image name to the plist like

```
Category1
-imageName
-item0
-name
-coordinates
-item1
```

I assume that you load the plist as dictionary, then you can access the name with

```
NSString *catName = @"Catergory1";
NSDictionary *dict = ...
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dict objectForKey:catName] valueForKey:@"imageName"]];
```

Comment: If I put "NSString *catName = @"Catergory1";" then my other category will be without image

Comment: @PavelKaljunen That was just an example how to access the categories via a variable. Add an image for every category in the plist, later set the category name whose image you want to show.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Then loop over all categories. Objective-C has a nice object enumerator.